# Which namespace does operator<< (stream) go to?

Tags: c++, operators, namespaces, conventions

If I have have some overloaded ostream operators, defined for library local objects, is its okay for them to go to std namespace? If I do not declare them in std namespace, then I must use `using ns:: operator <<`.

As a possible follow-up question, are there any operators which should go to standard or global namespace?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to Koenig Lookup (C++ Standard 3.4.2) `operator<<` will be searched in namespaces of arguments. No need to declare it in `std` namespace.

Comment: so, if I have object/class from external C library in global namespace, should I declare operators in global namespace as well?

Comment: I think that it is a good idea to declare operators in namespace where its argument from.

Answer (score 25):

`operator<<( ..., MyClass )` should go in the same namespace as `MyClass`. You should think of it as part of the interface of `MyClass`, even though it happens to be (necessarily) a non-member function.

A couple of references:

- My article [What's In a Class?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm).
- [C++ Coding Standards](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm) Item 57: "Keep a type and its nonmember function interface in the same namespace."

Comment: The exception to the rule of putting all related things in one namespace is partial specializations related to MyClass, e.g., for std::hash, std::less, std::swap, etc. which go in ::std::.

Answer (score 8):

The C++ Standard explicitly forbids you from declaring your own constructs in the std namespace.

Comment: std::swap is a notable exception.  You are specifically allowed to provide template specialization of std::swap, which must reside in the std namespace

Comment: `std::swap` is no exception.  You can provide specializations for any standard library templates.

Comment: There is also `std::hash` which is supposed to be overloaded in order to support `std::unordered_map`. Can anyone provide a definitive link to where C++ Std forbids declarations in the `std` namespace?

Answer (score 2):

It is generally a bad practice to declare anything (types, operators, etc ...) to be a part of a namespace you do not own.  This can have unexpected consequences for people consuming your library.  A better solution is to define your own namespace and to import both `std` and your namespace when you need to combine solutions.